# Using Log4j my application generates many log files every day

Tags: java, logging, web-services

I have a web services and I am using LOG4J but every day my application generate many log files that in a few days fills a lot of memory space overflowing the disk capacity.

I don't have a property file or configuration on web.xml

I have this:

```
public class OrchestrationDEServices {

static Logger log;

public OrchestrationDEServices() {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    log = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + ".class");
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        double d = Double.parseDouble(strNum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public static JSONArray ctrlHistAcadByCodigoService(String codigo) {
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    SqlConnection conx = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    if (isNumeric(codigo)) {
        try {
            conx = new SqlConnection();
            conx.Open();
            conn = conx.getConnection();
            jArray = new JSONArray();

            jArray = ResponseDE_Services.histAcadByCodigoRE(conn, codigo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + " --> Excepcion Exepcion general", e);
        } finally {

            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.warn(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + " --> Se intento cerrar Connection", e);
            }

            try {
                if (conx != null) {
                    conx.Close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + " --> Se intento cerrar SqlConnection", e);
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.error(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + " Codigo de estudiante no es tipo entero");
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}

Please, any suggestion to my trouble?

Comment: What is the exact problem? You want to make logs take less space or you want to figure out why logging occurs too frequently? Or...?

Comment: I want to know why logging occurs too frequently?